# T-SQL Subquery Question

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have two queries. 
For each tuple of query1 i want to run query2. i dont want to use cursors. i tried several approaches using subqueries.

query1:

```
select 
    distinct 
    category, 
    Count(category) as CategoryCount
from 
    mytable 
group by 
    category
```

query2:

```
select
   top 3 
   Text,
   Title,
   Category
from
    mytable
where
    Category = '1'
```

`Category = '1'` is a sample. the value should come from query1

Comment: you always need top 3 form mytable for each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH TBL AS
(
SELECT TEXT, TITLE, CATEGORY,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CATEGORY) AS CATEGORYCOUNT,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RC
FROM MYTABLE
)
SELECT TEXT, TITLE, CATEGORY, CATEGORYCOUNT
FROM TBL
WHERE RC <= 3
ORDER BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: which version of SQL are you running? This will not work on 2000. Only 2005+

Comment: but without the WHERE RC <= 3 exactly what i want.

Comment: select @@version returns 
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64)   Nov 24 2008 16:17:31   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: it looks like the distinct is applied and the top is ignored.

Comment: @Nick: You should get a maximum of 3 rows per category with this query. However, there could be less

Comment: I try to analyze this. Need to do some smaller test data. Come back to you soon!